# Async and onCreate error

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to android and try to send mail with 3rd part api.I done almost all coding then I found that android 3.0+ wont allow to do networking operations on main thread and the only way is to add it in Async.Below is my code after extending the activity to Async.But I get a error "Void is an invalid type for the variable onCreate".I dont know what should be the valid type for the variable onCreate.Could anyone solve the issue?Thanks

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
//import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ZZZ extends Activity{
public class done extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
  super.onCreate(icicle); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

  Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email); 
  addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
      Mail m = new Mail("my@domain.com", "password"); 

      String[] toArr = {"mail1@domain.com", "mail2@domain.com"}; 
      m.setTo(toArr);
      m.setFrom("mymail@gmail.com"); 
      m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Android device."); 
      m.setBody("Email body."); 

      try { 
        m.addAttachment("/storage/somethinghere"); 

        if(m.send()) { 
          Toast.makeText(ZZZ.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else { 
          Toast.makeText(ZZZ.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
      } catch(Exception e) { 
        //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
      } 
    } 
  });


}}
}
}
```

Comment: oh my. well.. you want to define the AsyncTask as a separate class, and then create the AsyncTask _within_ your onCreate method of your activity, and whenever you want to kick it off, you do so like a thread by invoking `start()`....

Comment: Sorry...I dont understand what you mean.Still a noob learning java+android.So could you please be a little brief?A big brief is also welcome :D.But please no bullying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. What we have here is an attempt to do Android development before knowing the most basic stuff about Java (and Android..). In Java you can't define a method inside of a method. Also, `AsyncTask` has to define the precise work you want done in the background and then what you'd like performed back on the main thread when that work compltes. You are here mixing the `AsyncTask` with the `Activity`. You have defined an inner class (the `AsyncTask`), but then inside of the `doInBackground` method of the `AsyncTask`, you start trying to override the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` class. Seems like a copy-paste gone horribly wrong. You'll never resolve these types of problems unless you back away from Android for a bit and just learn Java/general programming. You cannot just wrap arbitrary code inside of `AsyncTask` and expect it to resolve all the problems of performing long-running work on the main thread because...well this doesn't even compile.

You need to set up your button and `onClickListener` inside of `onCreate` of the Activity and then have that `onClick` fire the `AsyncTask` by creating a new instance of that inner class you define and calling `execute()` on it.

Here's the basic structure:

```
public class ZZZ extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button = new Button(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              new MyTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }


    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;   //do stuff here.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //manipulate UI thread here when the background work is done
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol...yeah...trying to do without having some knowledge about it proves epic fail.I'm being trained on very basic java now and I'm been warned to walk before running but...Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: @user2329333 yeah I've been there man. Best of luck. Very mature of you to respond so well after I was admittedly a bit harsh on you ;)

Comment: Haha...I have done a mistake and I have to admit it :P.Not run away for it :)